# Dynamically pass table name in Lookup and For Each activity in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I need to create a solution using ADF to compare Dev & Prod environments(all tables) on Azure SQL Server (different for Dev & Prod environments) and highlight the table differences.
I am using sys.objects to read the list of all tables in Lookup activity(First lookup activity),then pass each table name to ForEach activity wherein second Lookup transformation would read record counts against that table in Prod & Dev environments and compare the record counts between them, finally performing some activity.
I want to know how can I pass each table name read in First Lookup activity to second lookup activity inside ForEach Loop ?

Eg. Outer Lookup activity reads tables A, B, C, D and pass each table name one at a time inside ForEach wherein another lookup would execute something like below query in Prod and Dev environments :

```
Select count(*) from A ---in first iteration
then Select count(*) from B ---in second iteration
Select count(*) from C ---in third iteration and so on.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, your first layer should be like this:

[image]

For example, the Look Up Activity preview data as below:

[image]

The configuration of ForEach Activity:

[image]

Then the second Look Up Activity inside ForEach Activity should be configured as below:

[image]

Query sql:

```
@concat('select count(*) from ', item())
```

If you have further nested requirement, you could do the same thing.